# Python deletion of files - "Currently being used by another process"

Tags: python, image, file-handling

**Requirement**

I have to try to create a program that deletes all corrupted images (and images that are smaller than 400x400) and filters the rest of the images into groups of 10,000.

**Problem**

Currently when I try and delete any image that is "corrupt" it says the file is currently in use by another process per error below:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

**Steps taken**

I have tried multiple ways to set the file free including using a "back pedal" strategy where the application moves on to the next image then back pedals to try delete that one but it still remains open.
If I try delete the image manually while Python is open, it happily goes through.

**Please see code below:**

---

```
def confirmIt():
#======== Confirm Selection and Move files to new sub-directory:
if not folderPath.get() == "":                          ## make sure not blank
    source = folderPath.get()                           ## set source path 
    size = 0
    broken = False

    for fname in os.listdir(source):
        if  fname.lower().endswith(extensions):
            imageName = source+"\\"+fname               ## set the source location of the image
            try: 
                img = Image.open(imageName)
                width, height = img.size                    ## get the dimensions
                size = width * height / 1000
                broken = False
                img.close()
            except IOError, e:
                broken = True
                img.close()

            if ( broken == True ):
                def handleRemoveReadonly(func, path, exc):
                    excvalue = exc[1]
                    if func in (os.rmdir, os.remove) and excvalue.errno == errno.EACCES:
                        os.chmod(path, stat.S_IRWXU| stat.S_IRWXG| stat.S_IRWXO)
                        func(path)
                    else:
                        raise
                try:
                    os.remove(imageName)                ## Remove all remaining images that don't match the preset requirements (<400 and is an image)
```

**Extra Info**

Please note that I am using a GUI as well so the "resultMessage" and similar output/input fields are for this reason.

---

**EDIT:**

After back and forth discussions with @Cyphase I have identified where the issues were. The down posts were due to my editing of the OP with tracebacks for him.  I don't really use this forum as I don't usually have to code.  Further topics of this app may occur. Thanks.

---

Comment: Are you sure some other process isn't holding the file open? Also, why are you defining `handleRemoveReadonly()` in an if block when you're not even using it?

Comment: Which statement is the error message coming from, the `open`, `rmdir` or the `remove`?

Comment: Note that the removal should work under POSIX even if another process is using the file. Perhaps you should consider tagging it with whatever OS you're using (I'd guess windows).

Comment: Seems you are working under Microsoft (I suggest you to use `os.path.join` instead of `source+"\\"+fname`), I do not know the way to unlock files (probably using `ctypes` with the right syscalls) but you could [use a tool like](http://www.howtogeek.com/128680/how-to-delete-move-or-rename-locked-files-in-windows/) like [Process Explorer from Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see what process is locking them and trying to fix the issue.

Comment: CFNZ_Technie and @Cyphase, I have rolled back the edits which ask about the size restriction on the image uploads. That is a separate problem, and should be asked as a separate question.

Comment: @Matt, I had the same thought, but it _was_ actually part of the original question. I wasn't quite sure about the best way to proceed.

Comment: @Cyphase: It was part of the code, but wasn't part of the problem statement. Either way, the question has had over 15 revisions, and this question and your answer have accrued over 75 comments on them. It's really time for CFNZ_Technie to start a new question.

Comment: CFNZ_Techie, if you do open a new question, I'd appreciate if you post the link here and mention me so I'll see it :).

Comment: @Matt thank you I was thinking that but the progress was going good so didn't want to interrupt it.

Comment: @Cyphase http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100777/python-file-deletion-takes-a-long-time-to-delete-files:  I've created this one a little more tidier and also more accurate of what is required (for now)

Comment: @Cyphase hey dude i posted a question regarding the code you provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106709/typeerror-nonetype-when-using-return-zip-longest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much back-and-forth, this code should do what you want, barring any bugs :). To anyone else; there may be a few more changes made to iron out any kinks.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import errno
import os

try:
    from itertools import zip_longest  # Python 3
except ImportError:  # Python 2
    from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest  # Python 2

from PIL import Image

DEFAULT_IMAGE_EXTS = ('.jpg',)


# From the recipes section of the itertools documentation:
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)


def makedirs(d):
    try:
        os.makedirs(d)
    except OSError as e:
        # If the file already exists, and is a directory
        if e.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(d):
            created = False
        # It's some other error, or the existing file is not a directory
        else:
            raise
    else:
        created = True

    return created


def get_valid_filenames(directory, extensions):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.lower().endswith(extensions):
            yield filename


def get_corrupt_image_filenames(directory, extensions=DEFAULT_IMAGE_EXTS):
    for filename in get_valid_filenames(directory, extensions):
        image_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        try:
            with open(image_path, 'rb') as filehandle:
                Image.open(filehandle)
                # img = Image.open(filehandle)
                # img.load()  # I don't think this is needed, unless
                #               the corruption is not in the header.
        except IOError:
            yield filename


def confirm_it(directory, extensions, images_per_dir=5000):
    # Confirm selection and move files to new sub-directory
    if directory:
        for corrupt_file_name in get_corrupt_image_filenames(directory):
            os.remove(os.path.join(directory, corrupt_file_name))

        valid_images = get_valid_filenames(directory, extensions)
        grouped_image_file_names = grouper(valid_images, images_per_dir)
        for subdir, image_filenames in enumerate(grouped_image_file_names):
            for filename in image_filenames:
                from_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
                to_dir = os.path.join(directory, str(subdir))
                to_path = os.path.join(to_dir, filename)

                makedirs(to_dir)

                os.rename(from_path, to_path)


def confirm_it_wrapper():
    confirm_it(directory=folderPath.get(), extensions=extensions)
```

Use `confirm_it_wrapper` in place of `confirm_it` as the callback for the tkinter `Button` click.

Comment: @CFNZ_Techie, corrupt files should already be removed, unless you're removing that code.

Comment: I will create a new issue soon and made yours the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you are modifying the underlying filesystem (by deleting images) and then looping over the (old) list of files.

This is why your loop tries to open images that do not exist anymore.

The solution is to store the list of files first, then loop over the list of files; and not the output of `os.listdir()` (which will be cached).

You should also factor out a few components of your code. Try this version:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

# https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

def get_valid_images(image_path):
    extensions = ['*.jpg']
    return [f for f in os.listdir(image_path)
            if f.lower().endswith(extensions)]

def is_valid_image(image_path):
    try:
        img = Image.open(image_path)
        img.load()
        width, height = img.size
        img.close()
        return True
     except IOError as e:
        print(e)
        img.close()
        return None
     finally:
        img.close()
    return None

def confirmIt():
    # Confirm selection and move files to new sub-directory
    source = folderPath.get()  # set source path
    if not source:
        return False # If there is no source no point going
                     # head
    file_list = get_valid_images(source)
    valid_images = []
    for fname in file_list:
        image_dim = is_valid_image(os.path.join(source, fname))
        if image_dim:
            valid_images.append(source)

    # Now, group the resulting list in bunches for your move
    for dir_num, filenames in enumerate(grouper(valid_images, 5)):
        dest = os.path.join(source, str(dir_num))
        if not os.path.exists(dest):
            try:
                os.makedirs(dest)
            except OSError, e:
                print(e)
                continue # Skip this set, as we cannot make the dir
        for fname in filenames:
            shutil.move(fname, dest)
            print('Moving {}'.format(fname))
```

Comment: Hi Buhan... Thank you for this, I did not take into consideration that the os.listdir stores these in cache mode.  I will wait and see what Cyphase has come up with as we have come out to a final working situation, if you have any input to add to his that would be great.