# TypeError: NoneType - When using return zip_longest

Tags: python, windows, typeerror, nonetype

I am getting a type error for NoneType at the moment this is (I assume when I am trying to return a value in a function for zip_longest)

The objective of my code is to remove image files that are smaller the "width = 400 AND height = 400" and then placing all remaining images into folders of x value (where x can be changed later on).  Currently the code seems to work but I get the issue I mentioned and would like to prevent that error.

**Code:**

```
# ======== grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx:
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    print(fillvalue)
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)


def makedirs(d):
    try:
        os.makedirs(d)
    except OSError as e:
        # If the file already exists, and is a directory
        if e.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(d):
            created = False
        # It's some other error, or the existing file is not a directory
        else:
            raise
    else:
        created = True

    return created


def get_valid_filenames(directory, extensions):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.lower().endswith(extensions):
            yield filename


def get_too_small_image_filenames(directory, extensions=DEFAULT_IMAGE_EXTS,
                                  min_width=400, min_height=400):
    for filename in get_valid_filenames(directory, extensions):
        image_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        try:
            with open(image_path, 'rb') as filehandle:
                img = Image.open(filehandle)
                width, height = img.size
        except IOError, e:
                yield filename

        if (width < min_width) and (height < min_height):
            yield filename


def confirm_it(directory, extensions, images_per_dir=500):
    # Confirm selection and move files to new sub-directory

        for too_small_filename in get_too_small_image_filenames(directory):
            os.remove(os.path.join(directory, too_small_filename))

        valid_images = get_valid_filenames(directory, extensions)
        grouped_image_file_names = grouper(valid_images, images_per_dir)
        for subdir, image_filenames in enumerate(grouped_image_file_names):
            for filename in image_filenames:
                from_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)

                to_dir = os.path.join(directory, "Folder ("+str(subdir)+")")
                to_path = os.path.join(to_dir, filename)

                makedirs(to_dir)
                os.rename(from_path, to_path)


def confirm_it_wrapper():
    confirm_it(directory=folderPath.get(), extensions=extensions)
```

**Traceback:**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Gavin\workspace\Test Projects\src\Test0.py", line 109, in confirm_it_wrapper
    confirm_it(directory=folderPath.get(), extensions=extensions)
  File "C:\Users\Gavin\workspace\Test Projects\src\Test0.py", line 99, in confirm_it
    from_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 66, in join
    p_drive, p_path = splitdrive(p)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 114, in splitdrive
    if len(p) > 1:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

**Extra Information:**

As mentioned I believe it comes from the a function returning the "zip_longest" parameters where fillvalue is set to "None" in the creation. Any way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: @Cyphase if you have any advice please feel free to let me know :)

Comment: `folderPath.get()` returned `None`, is all.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How can I divert that then? Because folder.path is passed parameters via tkinker that actually uses the path to move these files.  Which means "none" is not true because it has a path

Comment: Have you tried a simple `if not filename: continue` right before you assign the from path? Also, checking for None for the directory would be good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the number of files is not a multiple of `images_per_dir`, so the last group of `images_per_dir` images is padded with `None`'s. Add this `trim_grouper()` function to your code to take care of that:

```
from itertools import takewhile

def trim_grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    for group in grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=fillvalue):
        yield tuple(takewhile((lambda x: x), group))
```

Then in `confirm_it()`, replace:

```
grouped_image_file_names = grouper(valid_images, images_per_dir)
```

with:

```
grouped_image_file_names = trim_grouper(valid_images, images_per_dir)
```

That should do it.

Comment: That was my thoughts too didn't know how to go about fixing it. thanks bro!

Comment: Shot dude - worked like a charm! - had to add "import itertools" too my code as well but worked perfectly after :)

Comment: @CFNZ_Techie, whoops, forgot to mention that; but that was the reason I did `itertools.takewhile`, not just `takewhile` :).